# MAUI Grid overflows child ContentPage of parent TabbedPage on initial load and when resizing on Windows

Tags: layout, grid, maui, tabbedpage

I have this [issue filed in github with the MAUI team](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20028) as a bug but looking for any ideas for a workaround?

I have a simple layout in a Grid below.

```
    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto">
        <SearchBar />
        <ListView Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>ListView Item</x:String>
                    <!-- Whole lot 'O items -->
                    <x:String>ListView Item</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
        <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="2">
            <Button Text="Display Content Page" Clicked="ContentPageButton_Clicked" />
            <Button Text="Display Tabbed Page" Clicked="TabbedPageButton_Clicked" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

When this is in a child page of a TabbedPage, the buttons at the bottom are not visible because the Grid overflows the height of the window. This happens upon initial display and as well as when resizing below a certain height.

Actual layout:

[image]

Expected layout:

[image]

[I have a repro](https://github.com/dalchri/MauiTabbedPageWindowsResizeRepro) that let's you view the exact same page without the TabbedPage as a parent and the layout performs as expected.

Any ideas how to workaround this issue?  Thanks for any suggestions!!!

Comment: I tested the demo you posted. It will cause the issue when you do not set a height for the listview. You can set the height for the Listview then it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the feedback, in the end your responses got me part of the way there!

I found one odd hack that seems to refresh the layout of the child page below.  This is working consistently for all page sizes and upon initial display of the page.

In the TabbedPage xaml:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1"
        x:Class="MauiApp1.TabbedPage" 
        SizeChanged="TabbedPage_SizeChanged"
```

In the code behind:

```
    private void TabbedPage_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CurrentPage.HeightRequest = this.Height;
        this.CurrentPage.HeightRequest = -1;
    }
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks for the solution! Pretty weird, though... it was working propertly with Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `App.xaml.cs` change :

```
// MainPage = new TabbedPage();
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TabbedPage());
```

[NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage?view=net-maui-8.0) allow you to, well, navigate with `Navigation.PushAsync` so you should use that instead of `Application.Current.MainPage = new TabbedPage();`.

You can also go with the [AppShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/create?view=net-maui-8.0).

Now to why it resolve your specific problem, no clues. My best guess is that the MainPage is not intended (and tested) to get much else than a `NavigationPage` or a `Shell` which produce some shenanigans on the layout (both implements IPageContainer, that may do something at this level).

Comment: I gave this a shot and it did help reduce the frequency of the problem but I noticed I still have the problem when the window is made too small.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can use the `ScrollView` as a workaround. Besides, if you make the window to the full screen, it also can show the button.

```
<ScrollView>
    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto">
    <SearchBar />
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>ListView Item</x:String>
                <x:String>ListView Item</x:String>
   
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
    </ListView>
 
    </StackLayout>
   
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2">
          <HorizontalStackLayout>
        <Button Text="Display Content Page" Clicked="ContentPageButton_Clicked" />
        <Button Text="Display Tabbed Page" Clicked="TabbedPageButton_Clicked" />
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Looking for a solution that duplicates the behavior of the ContentPage without the TabbedPage as a parent.